# c# store session without asp.net web

Tags: c#, web-services, session

Is there any way a c# server can store Sessions for web without developing the web in asp.net?
We have this web in angular and I want to improve performance of our server and I have 2 ways:

1. make some caching in the server with a singleton which store data
2. store sessions

Problem with 1 is that there are too many locks in code which im affried will cause a bottleneck (such as User log in, insert him to a "logged users" list for future locks on the user object).

So 2 will probably works best, but, is there anyway to build such thing? I can seem to find any reference to such thing without using the asp.net web.
Comminucation in web is done via AJAX request so I think, perhaps im wrong, that I can't maintain a TCP connection with the web so Reactor type server cannot help me.

TIA.

Comment: Have you looked into caching servers such as http://redis.io/ ?

Comment: actually i haven't. how well do you think it will perform?

Comment: I think it will perform very well but not sure how much effort it would be to set up.  I'll be looking at it in more detail myself in the coming months.

Comment: took into consideration. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe StateServer will solve your issue. You can store sessions via StateServer service in another server. Then you can manage it easily.

Comment: allocating another server just to store the states of users will surely cause a bottleneck similar to my first suggested option.